# include() and require_once() Issue

Tags: php, path, include, subdirectory, require-once

I have this situation:

```
/

index.php

/init (folder)

      init.php (of course inside this file I use require_once for db/function/and whatever you want to put inside)

/layout_parts (folder)

     header.php (and others common parts are inside this folder)
     
/my_space (folder inside layout parts)

      my_file.php

      another_file.php
     
/your_space (folder inside layout parts)
      
      your_file.php
      
      another_file.php
     
/third_space (folder inside layout parts)

      third_file.php

      another_file.php
```

For the index I have no problem it all works fine, but if I `include header.php` in one of the subfolder files my `require_once(init/init.php);` that is on the top of header.php won't work.

(Warning message says no such file in the directory (OF COURSE THE FILE EXIST) and it write down the subfolder directory that is not the path I expected).

I tried `echo $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT];` to see the whole path, `echo __DIR__;` to see which is the right path to the directory, no way out.

I know is such a dummy question but if some kind heart could help me it would be great. Thanks

Comment: `../` add this in your `include` or `require_once()`  file path  like :- `../init/init.php`

Comment: yep i already tried that way it just Warnings the same thing just adding the ../ before the path... :'(

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180459/making-php-includes-work-in-a-sub-directory?

Comment: It's important to remember that if you include/require a file that includes/requires other files, all relative paths will be relative from the file that does the including, not the file itself. The best way is to do: `require __DIR__ . '/relative/from/this/file.php`. __DIR__ gives you the absolute path from the file it's written in.

Comment: The issue with what you have is that in layout_parts you would need `../` in my_space you would need `../../` and so on the deeper you go.

Comment: @Aciddiz  check Magnus Eriksson   comment

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yep i'm reading it and try what fix my problem.. TY :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to use absolute paths instead of relative ones. When you use relative paths, you have to worry each time about how many levels deep you are and then have that many `../` etc. This is messy and difficult to manage, for eg, if you move a file to a different location, you have to update the includes again, based on where you are now. This is why absolute paths are helpful.

So create something like this:

```
$appRoot = "/path/to/root/folder/";
```

This is the path where the index.php file is located. It is the "application root", if you will.

Now, in ANY file where you want to include `init.php` add the following line:

```
include_once($appRoot."init/init.php");
```

Ideally the `$appRoot` should be created in a `global config` located in root. If you do not have a structure where a univeral config can be added, it can still be messy and you might need to add absolute paths into individual files (which is not a good idea)

Comment: yes what you wrote is kind of what i'm looking for, but really i can't escape this situation..
let's say i make a file called path.php where i define $appRoot or even a series of costant that lead me to the folder i want.. always work fine in my index, but as i enter in a subfolder page it gives me that warning, but it's sure something i miss in the whole design, i'll eat something and see if the carbos of the pasta helps.. TY